# How to get a DIV to be the correct width in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, width

This sounds pretty simple, but I am stuck.  I need to set a DIV to be 434 pixels wide in IE8.  The following is my code.  This works in FF, but IE8 always renders the DIV with a width of 414 pixels.  Why does it chop off 20 pixels?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #box
    {
        width:434px;
        background-color:red;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried it in strict mode, with the same result.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? Any answer here helped you?

Comment: Nope, never found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

IE does weird things with scroll bars, and accounts those in the width. What happens when you take the   out?

Comment: I added overflow:hidden to both BODY and #box, with no change.

Answer (score 0):

Elmonty, please look how not only width but height is shorter in IE8. I think this is a common rendering issue. The canvas in IE8 will show you the objects shorter than the other browsers do. As an example, load [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762933/how-to-get-a-div-to-be-the-correct-width-in-ie8/3763043#3763043) in both browsers and Alt+Tab between both and you will see what is going on...

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

<s>Somewhere before I faced a problem of margins. I don't remember for sure, but I changed the set the values for margin & padding as this :</s>

```
margin :0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding :0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

rather than :

```
margin :0;
padding :0;
```

Please try this little change & let me know if this was what was chopping your 20px.

---

**EDIT : Please ignore this answer as it is inappropriate.**

As pointed out by raymon, the browsers would render the piece of code you gave exactly the same. Your problem is probably due to some other factors....

Comment: Could you please explain why IE8 interprets both specifications different?

Comment: Ramon, it doesn't differ. I just rechecked the place where this had solved my problem....It was actually in context to one of parent elements where it cancelled out the padding set by the parent. Sorry...my bad, spoke without thinking.